# Skip Identity Verification

Tags: login, identity-verification

In Summer 20, Salesforce allowed us to "[Allow Highly Trusted Users to Skip Identity Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_auth_skip_identity_confirmation.htm&type=5&release=226)" which very plainly specified the intent.

In Winter 21, you took this away pretending it was only meant for Salesforce Customer Support. "[Skip Identity Confirmation at Login Permission was Clarified](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_auth_skip_login.htm&release=228&type=5)"

How can we restore the capabilities we had? Is there a different permission we should use?

Note: We only use this in non-production uses, though often for Dev orgs which use the production login.salesforce.com URL.

Comment: The obvious solution is to use something like [Salesforce Logins by Synebo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-logins-by-syne/mhpbcjokcjoldhjcapkcmfkkkgepapgm?hl=en) - a Chrome extension - and configure the login to include the security token. Since you have the security token you are never asked to confirm identity.

Comment: The only out of the box option is to use trusted IPs - see at the bottom of https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_auth_setup_identity_verification.htm&type=5